# UIControlEventTouchCancel not triggering the function

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, uicontrolevents

I have two buttons in my xib file. This is my interface file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *testButtonOut;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button2;

- (IBAction)testButton:(id)sender;
- (void)buttonReleased;

@end
```

These are the implementations of two functions in my implementation file

```
- (IBAction)testButton:(id)sender {
    button2.highlighted=YES;
   [testButtonOut addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonReleased) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchCancel];
}

- (void)buttonReleased{
    button2.highlighted=NO;
}
```

When I click on the testButton and release, it does not trigger the buttonReleased function (I used breakpoint to check it), but **if I change UIControlEventTouchCancel to UIControlEventTouchUpInside it does trigger the buttonReleased function when I click on it but I dont want to trigger it on button click I want to trigger it on button release, I also tried with TouchUpOutside but that didnt trigger as well.**  Which event should I use so that it calls the buttonReleased function when I release the click from the button event?

Comment: Use "UIControlEventTouchUpOutside" if you want an event when the finger is outside the bounds of the control.

Comment: As I mentioned TouchUpOutside didnt work either

Answer (score 0):

Instead of
    "UIControlEventTouchCancel" use
    "UIControlEventTouchUpInside."

Comment: I need to trigger the function only when button is released. Read my question fully.

Comment: Some of the touch events don't work for UIButton. If you want to implement as per your requirement you can make use of touchesEnded method of UIResponder chain.

Comment: how should I add touchesEnded to behave the way I desire, I tried something like this, but this didnt get fired when I clicked and release the button -(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    forgotUnderline.highlighted=NO;
}

Comment: You have to add following lines to it.. UItouch * touch=[touches any object]; if(touch.view==your_button){forgotUnderline.highlighted=NO;}

Comment: Yes, but still the touchesEnded method doesnt get fired when I release the button click.